# Different string to access resource in java

Tags: java, windows

I'm learning how we can access resources in java independently. So I have tried different ways as the listed below using `File` class.

```
    System.out.println("File .: " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File /:  " + new File("/").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File /.:  " + new File("/.").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File ./:  " + new File("./").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File ..:  " + new File("..").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("File ../:  " + new File("../").getAbsolutePath()); // why / not printed at the end?
    System.out.println("File /..:  " + new File("/..").getAbsolutePath()); 
    System.out.println("File /../:  " + new File("/../").getAbsolutePath()); // why / also not here
    System.out.println("File //:  " + new File("//").getAbsolutePath());  // why output is only \\  No path even
    System.out.println("File ..//:  " + new File("..//").getAbsolutePath()); // why not printed // at the end?
    System.out.println("File //..//:  " + new File("//..//").getAbsolutePath()); // why output \\.. only. No path even
```

Output is listed as below.

```
File .: D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\.
File /:  D:\
File /.:  D:\.
File ./:  D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\. // I'm expecting / at the end too.
File ..:  D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\..
File ../:  D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\.. // same above question
File /..:  D:\..
File /../:  D:\.. // same above question
File //:  \\            // Here why D:\ path not printed?
File ..//:  D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\..  
File //..//:  \\..        //strange same above.
```

Then I tried same things with `class`'s `getResource()` method. It works same as expected but on the last three lines I found exception by checking one by one Why?

```
    URL dot = Test.class.getResource(".");
    URL dotS = Test.class.getResource("./");
    URL S = Test.class.getResource("/");
    URL Sdot = Test.class.getResource("/.");
    URL ddot = Test.class.getResource("..");
    URL ddotS = Test.class.getResource("../");
    URL sdd = Test.class.getResource("/.."); 
    URL sdds = Test.class.getResource("/../");
    URL ss = Test.class.getResource("//");

    System.out.println("getR .: " + dot.toString());        
    System.out.println("getR /:" + S.toString());
    System.out.println("getR /.:" + Sdot.toString());
    System.out.println("getR ./:" + dotS.toString());
    System.out.println("getR ..:" + ddot.toString());
    System.out.println("getR ../:" + ddotS.toString());
    // System.out.println("getR /..:" + sdd.toString());  // Exception Here
    // System.out.println("getR /../:" + sdds.toString()); // Exception Here
    // System.out.println("getR //:" + ss.toString());     // Exception Here
```

I would like to ask Why `class`'s method getResource() throws `NullPointer` exception? and why the above `File`'s output is different? see the top code where I wrote // why?

I'm using Windows 10.

As I already mentioned, I'm learning resource accessing different ways. Then if you have any useful links please share that too.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: On many file systems (including, I expect, Windows 10, although I haven't tested it), the `/` directory has no parent, so the resource path `"/.."` cannot resolve to anything.

Comment: @csmckelvey `NullPointer` exception.

Comment: @TedHopp But `/` should go to `/out/` folder as in the other different examle it goes using `/` then `..` should move to one step up from `/out/` then why NullPointer exception?

Comment: Try messing around with `Path` interface, introduced in the Java SE 7 release, is one of the primary entrypoints of the java.nio.file package. If your application uses file I/O, you will want to learn about the powerful features of this class. You will hopefully have better clarity. `Paths` class is the helper class for `Path`

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran any help in the above issues or confusions?

Comment: You have a clear answer from @Ted Hopp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null pointer exception is because `Test.class.getResource()` is returning `null` for those last three path strings. This happens whenever the indicated resource could not be found. For security reasons, Java code isn't allowed to access (or even know about) resources outside the class path. The path `"/"` maps to the root directory of the class path used to load class `Test`. It looks from your output that this is `D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest` (or possibly `D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out`; you don't report the output from the second part of your experiment).

As to why the trailing slash disappears from your file paths, that's part of how `File#toString()` is supposed to work. According to the docs, [`File#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toString--) returns the same string as `File#getPath()`. The [docs for that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath--), in turn, say:

> The resulting string uses the default name-separator character to separate the names in the name sequence.

Note that the name separator character is used to *separate* the names. It doesn't preserve trailing separators (that don't separate anything).

I'm not sure why the absolute path for `"//..//"` is `"\\.."`. (Or, for that matter, why `"//.."` results in `"\\"`. It's easy to understand why the trailing `//` is suppressed; those are name separator characters that don't separate anything. On my Mac the output for both of those is `"/.."`. This behavior is obviously OS-dependent. I suspect that on Windows, the leading `"//"` represents a network path to a computer and the computer name is just absent.

Comment: Perfect. and the last think you have missed is `System.out.println("File //..//:  " + new File("//..//").getAbsolutePath()); // why output \\.. only. No path even` the output of this code is `File //..//:  \\..`

Comment: Sorry for being late again. The another output which is confusing now me that `File ../:  D:\8th Semester\Java\CMDProjects\ClassPathTest\out\..` this output should be equal to `D:\` because first using `..` go back one directory then `/` should represent as `D:\` as in the above second output. `File /:  D:\`

Comment: @UnKnown - No, for `"../"`, the trailing `/` has nothing to do with making the path absolute. It just separates `..` from the remainder of the relative path. Because the remainder is empty, it gets thrown away. It's only a *leading* `/` that turns a path into an absolute path (as in the second output).

Comment: I was expecting to execute it same as in `cmd` because I mostly read that `File` class works as local file system.

Comment: So `..` will not move the directory to one level up for `File` and `getResource`? just to confirm because somewhere I read the path as `\\..\\..\\filesomething.txt`

Comment: @UnKnown - `File` and `getResource` work differently. For `getResource`, `..` will not allow you to move outside the class loader's base directory. For `File`, I expect that the behavior varies across platforms.